# How to select rows where a column value is empty/null using Zend_Db?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, zend-db, zend-db-select

I have an SQLite database, eventually will be a MySQL database and I'm using Zend Framework. I'm trying to fetch all the rows in a table where the `'date_accepted'` column is empty/null/doesn't have a value. This is what I have so far:

```
public function fetchAllPending()
{
    $select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
    $select->where('date_accepted = ?', 'null');
    return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How would you write this in plain SQL, and/or using `Zend_Db_Select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible issues I see.  What is the function getDbTable?  If your class inherits from Zend_Db_Table that function shouldn't be necessary.  Second maybe you should try IS NULL instead of = null with quoting null into the query.

```
public function fetchAllPending()
{
        $select = $this->select()->where('date_accepted IS NULL');
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: this function is in my data mapper object. (not sure if it's the best place, but it works). but IS NULL worked for me, so thanks!

Comment: While using Zend 2.4.7's TableGateway, I found the following helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/32238396/3112527 .