# Set a value to null, when calling Zend_Db::update() and insert()

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

My question is the exact same as [How to Set a Value to NULL when using Zend_Db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173690/how-to-set-a-value-to-null-when-using-zend-db)

**However, the solution given in that question is not working for me.** My code looks like the following. I call `updateOper` on the Model class when update is clicked on the front end. Inside `updateOper`, I call another function `trimData()` where I first trim all whitespace and then I also check that if some of the fields are coming in `empty` or `''` I want to set them to default values or NULL values. Therefore I am using `new Zend_db_expr('null')` and `new Zend_db_expr('default')` .

The code is as follows:

```
private function trimData(&$data ) {

    //Trim whitespace characters from incoming data.
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
    { 
        $data[$key] = trim($val);
        if($data['notes'] == '') {
            error_log("set notes to null/default value");
            $data['notes'] = new Zend_db_expr('DEFAULT');
        }
    }

}

public function updateOper($data, $id)
{
    $result = 0;

    $tData = $this->trimData($data);

    error_log("going to add data as ".print_r($data, true));
    $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);
    $result = $this->update($data, $where);

    return $result;
}
```

The `error_log` statement prints the `$data array` as follows:

```
[id] => 10    
[name] => alpha
[notes] => DEFAULT
```

**As a result, the `notes` column has value ='DEFAULT' instead of picking the default value given in the table definition.**

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong, but have not been able to find a solution.
I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Another observation: I added an error log in trimData() function to print the value of notes after setting it to zend_db_expr and it prints : Value of notes after expr is `Zend_Db_Expr Object
(
    [_expression:protected] => DEFAULT
)
 However, when I am printing the same value in updateOper() function as part of the data array it doesnt show it as an object but just as a string DEFAULT. It needs to be interpreted as the object and then only this will work. But what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $data['notes'] is being changed to the `__toString()` value of the `Zend_Db_Expr` instead of preserving the actual object.

Maybe the reference is clogging things up. Else you may need to move the expression declaration into the actual update query.

Comment: Thanks RockyFord - this was the reason. I had to change the function signature of `trimData(&$data)` to `trimData($data)` and then return the modified `$data` array to `updateOper` function. Now it works fine.